# updating view using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to create a sample app which uses morrischart to render some of the data on the chart with 3 buttons. On click on each button the charting area should get rerendered with new set of graphs. Below is the code for html

Here is code

```
<div class="panel-body">
<linechart id="line-example" data-options="chart_options"></linechart>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer clearfix">
<a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="data('usage')" data="usage">
<i class="fa fa-tachometer fa-fw" ></i>Usage</a>
                                    <a href="#"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="data('cost')" data="cost">
<i class="fa fa-money fa-fw" ></i>Cost
</a>
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" ng-click="data('weather')" data="weather">
<i class="fa fa-soundcloud fa-fw" ></i>Weather</a>
 </div>
```

Javascript code to get data and populate into $scope.chart_options variable which is used in "linechart" element of html code.

====javascript

```
$scope.data = function(reporttype){
            console.log(reporttype);
            var data=customersFactory.getChartData(reporttype);
             $scope.chart_options = data;
        };
//initialize chart
data('usage');
```

It initalizes fine but when i click on button to update chart it calls data method correctly but immediately it call data('usage') again and overrides the values. I assume there should be a way to call method only during initialization time so that i can skip calling data method twice.

Thanks
Advance

Comment: Have you looked at wrapping the function with $interval?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? It's difficult to understand.

Comment: thanks oleg and austinthedeveloper. I rephrased my question. My problem is with data() method which called twice.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem was due to my controller initialized from UI using ng-init and reload method in js file also initializing. After removing from UI it worked  as expected.